# jQuery - Function is fired without clicking a button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

Login-modal has 2 buttons: "Login" and "Password reset" - by clicking the "password-reset-button", the "Login-modal" disappears and the "Password-Reset-Modal" appers. If you cancel the "Login-Modal", no Password-Reset-Modal" appers. Fine. However, after clicking the "password-reset-button" once, each time you cancel the "Login-Modal", the "Password-Reset-Modal" appears. 
Can someone please explain this strange behavior and how to bind this behavior to the click event? Thanks in advance!

```
$('button#loginModal-password-reset_button').bind('click', function() {
    $('#loginModal').modal('hide').on('hidden.bs.modal',
    function() {
        $('#password-resetModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Tried also the following without success

```
$('button#loginModal-password-reset_button').click(function(e) {

$(document).on('click', 'button#loginModal-password-reset_button', function(e){

$('button#loginModal-password-reset_button').on('click', function(e) {
```

Comment: Is this all your own code, or are you using a library/framework besides jQ? Also, generally, the more code (HTML here, maybe the end of the function you mentioned also trying) the better. Hope you get an answer.

Comment: Thanks Framework is Laravel 5.3 in combination with bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't Use event handler. Try This.

```
 $('button#loginModal-password-reset_button').bind('click', function() {
        $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
        $('#password-resetModal').modal('show');

    });
```

If You Like to Delay to open #password-resetModal

```
$('button#loginModal-password-reset_button').bind('click', function() {
        $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){ 
                   $('#password-resetModal').modal('show');
                   }, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. Solution 1 seems to be perfect. SolutIon 2 behaves kind of strange. The Passwort-Reset-Modal appears several times after clicking "loginModal-password-reset_button" once.

Comment: I edit SolutIon 2, Now it's also work fine. If this answer solve your problem .Please mark as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're adding an event handler inside another event handler. So every time you click on the reset button, you add another `hidden.bs.modal` handler on the modal, and these all run every time the modal is hidden.

Just add that handler once, and the password reset button should just hide it.

```
$('button#loginModal-password-reset_button').on('click', function() {
    $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
});
$('#loginModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#password-resetModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Tested, but doesn't work. Reset-Modal always shows up.